# Capture all input and output from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to capture all the input and output from a bash script that i created for installing nagios. I have it creating the log file using tee right now but it only shows when there is an echo command or some output from like "service httpd restart". I mainly want to capture the input the user is entering in the log file for future reference.

Answer (score 6):

The `script` command, run prior to your program, will capture all input and output to a file you specify.  It terminates with a ctrl-D.

```
script -c yourprogram filename
```

may do what you're looking for.  See the man page for script.